# absolutely positioned child div of fixed position parent div appearing on top of parent

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a fixed position menu-bar with a menu tray that floats from the left. all is working fine except for the fact that tray floating from the left's z-position is above the main menu.

As a result, I cannot see the bottom shadow I applied on the top menu bar.

```css
body {
  background: red;
}

.main-menu {
  position: fixed;
  background: #ffffff;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 1px 0 rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.6);
}

.left-menu {
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px 0 rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.6)
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="main-menu">
    <div class="left-menu"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to repeat the menu bar's shadow inside the left-menu, by using an inset box-shadow.

```css
body {
  background: red;
}

.main-menu {
  position: fixed;
  background: #ffffff;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 1px 0 rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.6);
}

.left-menu {
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px 0 rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.6),
              inset 0 3px 1px 0 rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="main-menu">
    <div class="left-menu"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

But I realise this is a bit of a kludge, and I hope there are better answers!

Comment: I can live with that solution for the time being as appearance wise it looks good. I still am very curious about why the child appears on top though. Oh well, Thanks!

Comment: @junior_2969 child by default are inside the parent container so it's normal you see it on *top* and here you are facing an overflow and thus the behavior

Answer (score 2):

I needed to make the two menu siblings to apply `z-index`. I also added some color for visuals. And since the two menu are now siblings, I needed to adjust the `top` of the `left-menu` similar to the height of the `main-menu`

```css
body {
  background: red;
}

.main-menu {
  position: fixed;
  background: #ffffff;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 1px 0 rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.6);
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: green;
}

.left-menu {
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px 0 rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.6);
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="main-menu">
  </div>
  <div class="left-menu"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't believe I can use this. My actual code is a lot more complicated than this. This left-menu is for mobile, when on desktop I need the menu to be inside the parent